# Fragment in Android app

Tags: android, fragment

I have completed the sequence of activities of my app for smartphone, but to use it in tablets want to give a more typical of this type of display can display more than one activity at a time. That is, if I have the app smartphone version the activities A -> B -> C -> D, I want to run with a tablet will represent A, B -> B, C -> B, D, so that simultaneously displays two screen activities.
I have read that this component is used "Fragment" but after reading some things I'm a little busy and I do not know exactly what steps to follow, if you could briefly tell me or show me a clear example I'd appreciate.

A greeting.

Comment: I'm sorry you're "a litle busy" as in too busy to figure out how to use fragments. Thank God the rest of us have an endless amount of free time to explain it to you.

Comment: I think he wanted to say confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a very good explanation](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-byle/android-tutorial-optimizing-phones-and-tablets-fragments) of how to display different fragments and as a result different layouts for phone and tablet. There are 2 generall aproaches (1) declare the fragments in you XML layout if you know which fragements you want to display in advance or (2) add the fragments to some container view at runtime in a layout specificly designed to accomidate a larger screen size.

If you're running only activities now you will need to convert your activities to run as fragments. This, for the most part, will mean dumping the contents of your `onCreate` method into the `onActivityCreated` method of your fragment. If you run into issues with this fast and dirty approach (I know you're busy as your question indicates) you should check when the variables or methods you use - if any are related to the underlying `FragmentActivity` - are created. I don't know the structure of your app so I cannot comment more than that.

Comment: It´s true, sorry for the confusion, I'm pretty confused, not busy. I know that the activities have to be FragmentActivity and must be used Fragment for classes within FragmentActivities, but I have some doubts about how to define layouts for each class.
I define a layout with 2 fragments for the class that inherits from FragmentActivity and each introduce a class that inherits from Fragment?
The classes that inherit from Fragment should be the classes to my app adapted that component Fragment?
Thank you again.

Comment: Could you post some code about how you're trying to acomplish this now? If I can see what you're trying I can explain what's wrong and show you how to do it.